# Loading model in view in CodeIgniter without breaking MVC Framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm really a newbie in MVC Framework and as well as in CodeIgniter. Is it possible to access model in view in CodeIgniter without breaking MVC framework? This is what I'm talking about.

Below is my code for my view.

```
foreach ($packages as $row)
{
    if($row->Category == "Wedding")
    {
        $package_name = $row->package_name;
        $ratings = $model->ratings($package_name);
        foreach ($ratings as $row_review)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And this is in my model

```
public function ratings($package_name)
{
    $this->db->select('round(sum(Rating)/count(Rating)) as total');
    $this->db->where('package_name', $package_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_review');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm talking about

This is my view,




foreach($packages as $row){
        if($row->Category == "Wedding"){
            $package_name = $row->package_name;
            $ratings = $model->ratings($package_name);
            foreach ($ratings as $row_review) {

            }}}

Comment: And this is my model
public function ratings($package_name){
    $this->db->select('round(sum(Rating)/count(Rating)) as total');
    $this->db->where('package_name',$package_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_review');
    return $query->result();
  }

Comment: you can do it with the help of `helpers` also without breaking MVC

Comment: Much worse than breaking the MVC pattern is the practice of running queries in a loop. Rewrite code that executes queries inside loops by moving the query outside of the loop and extending it to query all necessary data.

Comment: What generates the `$packages` data? There is a very strong chance that all the needed information - packages and ratings -  can be gathered with one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Note : your `database` and `model` should also be loaded either in controller or in `autoload.php`;*

*You can do it with the help of condeigniter's `helpers` . Create a file and  name it `custom_helper.php` and add it to helpers folder and load it with `autoload.php` like this :*

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');
```

In your `custom_helper.php` add a function like this :

```
function package_ratings($package_name)
{ 
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $ci->db->select('round(sum(Rating)/count(Rating)) as total'); 
    $ci->db->where('package_name',$package_name);
    $query = $ci->db->get('tbl_review'); 
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

In your view use `package_ratings` function as the given below :

```
foreach($packages as $row)
{ 
    if($row->Category == "Wedding")
    { 
        $package_name = $row->package_name; 
        $ratings = package_ratings($package_name); 
        foreach ($ratings as $row_review) 
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Queries in a loop? Really?

Answer (score 0):

In View can call the model function directly:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('your_model');// If the model was not loaded before(in controller or via autoloader).
....
$result = $CI->your_model->model_method();
```